# How to get average value ignoring some values of a field

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I know how to get the average between numbers, but when I try to do the same approach (by setting up the variable's properties) to get the average from mixed values of numbers and strings it always returns an exception (and I know why).

How to get the average value for a *column_1* with mixed values of numbers and string?

```
column_1
  3
  4
  N/A
  3
  N/A
```

Meaning to say, in column 1, the average must be `3.33.` The `(3+4+3)/3` formula should be applied, the two `N/A` values must be ignored/excluded from the computation. How to do that?

Comment: Show the jrxml code; show the exception.

Comment: what are data types of those two column in your jrxml ?

Comment: @DaveJarvis here's my variable's expression:
Double.valueOf($F{column_1}) .. obviously it will return an exception because N/A cannot be converted to double..
it appears on my java app. where the report is being called.
(java.lang.NumberFormatException)

Comment: @FahadAnjum its in String. Column 1 comes from a database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task can be decomposed into several simple subtasks:

1. Getting numeric value from mixed type. We should check the field for numeric value.
2. Calculating the average value for all numeric values (skipping non-numeric values).

For solving first subtask we can use Apache *commons-lang* library. The [***StringUtils.isNumeric(java.lang.CharSequence)***](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric(java.lang.CharSequence)) method help us to check if the value is numeric.

For solving second subtask we can use two variables - the first for storing numeric value and the second - for calculating average value.

## Working example

### Datasource

I used the csv datasource in this sample:

```
numValue
3
4
N/A
3
N/A
```

The name of data adapter for this datasource in the example below is *str_num.csv*. The first line from the file is skipped - it is contains the column's name.

### The report's template

I used *Jaspersoft Studio* (JSS) for designing a report template. The *Detail* band is using for showing data and the *Summary* band for showing average value.

The field with values (numeric and non-numeric) will be of the ***java.lang.String*** type.

The first variable is for storing only numeric values. We are initializing the variable with **null** if the value

The expression will be:

```java
StringUtils.isNumeric($F{numValue}) ? Integer.valueOf($F{numValue}) : null
```

The *Java* library is using in this expression, this is why we need to set report's language as *java* and add import for class *StringUtils*.

The second variable will of *Average* calculation type:

```xml
<variable name="averageValue" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Average">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{number}]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

The full template:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Average value" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="bee405b0-c35a-442a-841d-f51423c1c797">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="str_num.csv"/>
    <import value="org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="numValue" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="number" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[StringUtils.isNumeric($F{numValue}) ? Integer.valueOf($F{numValue}) : null]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="averageValue" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Average">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{number}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
    </variable>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="230" height="30" uuid="9d00d7e3-b9bc-404d-8842-728326a5d2df"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Original value: " + $F{numValue}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="230" y="0" width="250" height="30" uuid="4509cae9-3b89-4860-838a-36aa4466fb37"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Only numeric value: " + $V{number}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <summary>
        <band height="53">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="230" height="30" uuid="937af139-259c-49da-a0d9-191bcf801cca"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Average value (non numeric values are skipped):]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="0.00">
                <reportElement x="230" y="0" width="140" height="30" uuid="9abd786b-32ee-4ab1-91dc-851e8bfef0db"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{averageValue}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

#### Output result

The generated resut in *JSS* looks like this:

[image: The result in JSS. Average of 3 records]

If we will change the expression of first variable (for storing numeric values) to this one:

```java
StringUtils.isNumeric($F{numValue}) ? Integer.valueOf($F{numValue}) : 0
```

the result will be:

[image: The result in JSS. Average of 5 records]

- It is the average value for 5 records, not for 3 as in the first case above.

Comment: it returns null. instead of the average. i followed your guide, the only difference was, i displayed the *averageValue* variable directly to the summary band.

Comment: Did you check my example with your version of iReport? Does it work well?

Comment: yes it did.. but when i apply it to my main report, it returns null.
Actually the values of the *column_1* comes from a database.
So the values might change every time i call the report.
in my report, i have a group called *year*.. now i want to get the average of the values in *column_1* under the group of 1991 (for example).
sorry for my bad english. Thanks in advance :D